# How to hide option in Spring form?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to hide an option in a select dropdown in spring form. Anyone know how to do it?
The code below does not allow hidden attribute.

```
<form:select path="age" id="age" name = "age">
   <form:option hidden value=""  label="--Select age group--"/>
   <form:option value="1" label="below 18" />
   <form:option value="2" label="18 - 30" />
   <form:option value="3" label="30 - 45" />
   <form:option value="4" label="above 45" />
</form:select>
```

Comment: Have you tried using CSS and JS to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form:select path="age" id="age" name = "age">
    **<form:option hidden="true" value=""  label="--Select age group--"/>**
    <form:option value="1" label="below 18" />
    <form:option value="2" label="18 - 30" />
    <form:option value="3" label="30 - 45" />
    <form:option value="4" label="above 45" />
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title> </title> 
<script src="/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
  $("form").submit(function(){
      alert("submit is ok");
      return false;
  });
  $("button").click(function(){
    // Get the corresponding id to ids
     if(false){
         $("form").submit();
     }else{
         console.log('参数不全');
     }
  });  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- 隐藏域的input -->
<form action="">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="test"><br>
</form> 
<button>提交</button>
</body>
</html>
```